# JPA DDL Generator for generating SQL Query

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

My requirements are to create a table in a database under a schema. The schema is dynamically selected, so "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" is not a suitable solution for me. I can use an "HikariDataSource" to establish a connection with the database and execute a statement for table creation, but this would be considered "hardcoded" or somewhat "manual". Instead, I want to utilize the JPA create table job to retrieve the create DDL. Is this something that is exposed, or is it only for internal usage?

edit:
I have JPA Entity, so I want use JPA Entity to Create Table.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create tables dynamically. still  you can make use of metadata, schema dropper functionalities. but I recommend to use liquibase for database changes. check out this post. liquibase helps you to make db changes easy.
[Integrating liquibase with spring boot](https://medium.com/@vamsibvrit559/integrating-liquibase-with-spring-boot-8998905b3f06)